# Auto click button if style display is block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

everyone, I am totally new to this and I was just wondering, is there a way to auto click a button when styling `display:block`?

I would really appreciate **if someone can point me in the right direction.**

```html
<div id="advert" img="" style="display: block;">
  <div id="continueItems" class="text-center">
    <p> TEXT HERE</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button id="statsContinue" class="btn btn-primary text-center" data-itr="continue" onclick="closeStats();">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like `if (getComputedStyle(advert).display == 'block') statsContinue.click();` ?

Comment: You need to learn basics before understanding the concept. This is not a tutorial site. Learn the basics here https://www.w3schools.com/ Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the `display` property to `trigger()` the click the event:

```js
if($('#advert').css('display') == 'block')
  $('#statsContinue').trigger('click');
  
function closeStats(){
  console.log('auto click happened');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="advert" img="" style="display: block;">
<div id="continueItems" class="text-center">
<p> TEXT HERE</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="text-center">
<button id="statsContinue" class="btn btn-primary text-center" data-itr="continue" onclick="closeStats();">Continue</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the element is visible using `.is(':visible')` then trigger the click using `click()` like :

```js
if ($('#advert').is(':visible')) {
  $('#statsContinue').click();
}

function closeStats() {
  alert('Clik triggered');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="advert" img="" style="display: block;">
  <div id="continueItems" class="text-center">
    <p> TEXT HERE</p>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center">
    <button id="statsContinue" class="btn btn-primary text-center" data-itr="continue" onclick="closeStats();">Continue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```